# Not allowed to have sex because of her parents

Tags: hadith, nikah, parents, adultery

Asalamu alaikum brothers and sisters,

The situation is  that I live in Europe and my wife lives in Pakistan because I have not finished my study yet to have proper income for bringing my wife to Europe.

However it has been 1 year that I'm married with my wife.  And every year I will visit my wife in Pakistan to be together. My wife lives with her parents untill I have finished my study and have work and income.

The biggest problem that I have is that her parents don't want me to have sex with her. Sleeping with her is fine, but sex is taboo. I have to wait until the day that I have finished my study and started working to bring my wife into my home in Europe, then from that day on sex is no problem for them.

However I have a great desire to have intimacy with my wife. It is also my right to have intimacy because Allah (swt) have blessed me to get me married with her.

On the other hand I the parents of my wife trust me not having sex with her, which is now very difficult for me. I have already tought to have a temporary nikah with another girl to fulfill my sexual desires, but I did not do that because that should be betrayal on my wife.

My question is what I should do and what are my rights on an Islamic point of view?

Thanks in advance, may Allah (swt) bless you all.

Comment: AFAIK even and this is based on sunni view: As long as the wife didn't leave to her husbands house her father still is her guardian and according to this you should hurry up and finish studying and bring your wife to your place. Note that only the part of the question about your rights according the islamic point of view is on topic here!

Comment: Medi1Saif,  thanks for your comment. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Quran said:

> وَ إِنْ جَاهَدَاكَ عَلَىٰ أَنْ تُشْرِكَ بِي مَا لَيْسَ لَكَ بِهِ
> عِلْمٌ فَلَا تُطِعْهُمَا وَ صَاحِبْهُمَا فِي الدُّنْيَا مَعْرُوفًا وَ
> اتَّبِعْ سَبِيلَ مَنْ أَنَابَ إِلَيَّ ثُمَّ إِلَيَّ مَرْجِعُكُمْ
> فَأُنَبِّئُكُمْ بِمَا كُنتُمْ تَعْمَلُونَ 15
>
> Yet if either of them should strive to make you associate anything
> with Me which you have no knowledge about, do not obey them although
> you should (still) **keep company with both of them properly** during
> [their life in] this world. Follow the way of anyone who feels
> concerned about Me. Then to Me will be your return and I shall notify
> you about whatever you have been doing.)  [(15)](https://quran.inoor.ir/en/ayah/31/15/)

So it is necessary to treat them properly. As a solution, you can meet secretly at places other than your home, for example, a hotel. or at home when they are away from home. Also, you can talk to them properly and maybe you can convince them. and consider that it is a temporary situation that will pass soon. And make dua and ask God to help you bring your wife sooner.

> وَ قَالَ رَبُّكُمُ ادْعُونِي أَسْتَجِبْ لَكُمْ إِنَّ الَّذِينَ
> يَسْتَكْبِرُونَ عَنْ عِبَادَتِي سَيَدْخُلُونَ جَهَنَّمَ دَاخِرِينَ 60
>
> Your Lord has said, Call upon Me and I will answer you Surely those who wax too proud to do Me service shall enter Gehennam (Hell) utterly abject(60)
> [(60)](https://quran.inoor.ir/en/ayah/40/60/)